can't download replies to a comments on youtube using python
the code is able to get the commenters usernames and is able to click on the replies button to show the people that replie to a comment but i just can't get it to extract the usernames of the people that replied to a comment . i don't know why but i tried to extract the usernames of the people that replied but they just don't show up on the result
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def extract_usernames(video_url):
    # Initialize the Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Navigate to the video URL
    driver.get(video_url)

    # Wait for the page to load completely
    time.sleep(10)  # Increase this value if your internet connection is slow

    # Scroll to the bottom of the page to load all comments
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)  # Slowly scroll down to load all comments
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    # Find all the comment elements
    comment_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-comment-thread-renderer")

    # Extract the usernames from the comment elements (including replies)
    usernames = []
    for comment_element in comment_elements:
        # Click on the "View replies" button if it exists
        try:
            view_replies_button = comment_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#more-replies.more-button.style-scope.ytd-comment-replies-renderer")
            view_replies_button.click()
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait for replies to load after clicking
        except:
            pass

        extract_usernames_recursive(comment_element, usernames)

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

    return usernames

def extract_usernames_recursive(comment_element, usernames):
    # Extract the username from the top-level comment
    username_element = comment_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.style-scope.ytd-comment-view-model > a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-comment-view-model")
    username_link = username_element.get_attribute('href')
    if username_link.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/@'):
        username = username_link.split('@')[1]
        usernames.append(username)

    # Check for replies and extract usernames recursively
    reply_elements = comment_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-comment-thread-renderer")
    for reply_element in reply_elements:
        extract_usernames_recursive(reply_element, usernames)

# Example usage
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1III_DQU4I"  # Replace with the actual video URL
usernames = extract_usernames(video_url)
print(usernames)


Why not using YouTube Data API v3 CommentThreads: list and Comments: list endpoints, as shown in this Stack Overflow answer?

About this line: if username_link.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/@'):, can you add the else and see what the value of username_link is? - I think that not every user who replied will be loaded with a handle, it will instead have the channel_id. So, instead of https://www.youtube.com/@user1458... you might get https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCask47.... Change the code and let us know
